# Generated query with excessive subqueries performing poorly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this beast of a query that I inherited that doesn't perform very well. It's being generated by code and then run:

```
 WITH 
    cte_training AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid FROM _training),
    cte_00_0000_s AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vtbd FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_begin_date) = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='00-0000'),
    cte_00_0000_e AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vted FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_training_completed = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='00-0000'),
    cte_00_0000_d AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vdr FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_degree_received is not NULL AND Training_program_SOC = '00-0000'),
    cte_00_0000_c AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vcr FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND Vocational_license_received IS NOT NULL AND Training_program_SOC = '00-0000'),

    cte_11_9111_s AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vtbd FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_begin_date) = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='11-9111'),
    cte_11_9111_e AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vted FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_training_completed = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='11-9111'),
    cte_11_9111_d AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vdr FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_degree_received is not NULL AND Training_program_SOC = '11-9111'),
    cte_11_9111_c AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vcr FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND Vocational_license_received IS NOT NULL AND Training_program_SOC = '11-9111'),

...

    cte_99_9999_s AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vtbd FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_begin_date) = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='99-9999'),
    cte_99_9999_e AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vted FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_training_completed = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='99-9999'),
    cte_99_9999_d AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vdr FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_degree_received is not NULL AND Training_program_SOC = '99-9999'),
    cte_99_9999_c AS (SELECT DISTINCT rid, 'Yes' AS vcr FROM _training WHERE ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND Vocational_license_received IS NOT NULL AND Training_program_SOC = '99-9999')

SELECT cte_training.rid, 
        ISNULL(cte_00_0000_s.vtbd,'No') [00-0000 Started], 
        ISNULL(cte_00_0000_e.vted,'No') [00-0000 Completed],
        ISNULL(cte_00_0000_d.vdr, 'No') [00-0000 Degree],
        ISNULL(cte_00_0000_c.vcr, 'No') [00-0000 Certificate],

        ISNULL(cte_11_9111_s.vtbd,'No') [11-9111 Started], 
        ISNULL(cte_11_9111_e.vted,'No') [11-9111 Completed],
        ISNULL(cte_11_9111_d.vdr, 'No') [11-9111 Degree],
        ISNULL(cte_11_9111_c.vcr, 'No') [11-9111 Certificate],

...

        ISNULL(cte_99_9999_s.vtbd,'No') [99-9999 Started], 
        ISNULL(cte_99_9999_e.vted,'No') [99-9999 Completed],
        ISNULL(cte_99_9999_d.vdr, 'No') [99-9999 Degree],
        ISNULL(cte_99_9999_c.vcr, 'No') [99-9999 Certificate]

FROM cte_training
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_00_0000_s ON cte_training.rid = cte_00_0000_s.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_00_0000_e ON cte_training.rid = cte_00_0000_e.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_00_0000_d ON cte_training.rid = cte_00_0000_d.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_00_0000_c ON cte_training.rid = cte_00_0000_c.rid

LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_11_9111_s ON cte_training.rid = cte_11_9111_s.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_11_9111_e ON cte_training.rid = cte_11_9111_e.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_11_9111_d ON cte_training.rid = cte_11_9111_d.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_11_9111_c ON cte_training.rid = cte_11_9111_c.rid

...

LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_99_9999_s ON cte_training.rid = cte_99_9999_s.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_99_9999_e ON cte_training.rid = cte_99_9999_e.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_99_9999_d ON cte_training.rid = cte_99_9999_d.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_99_9999_c ON cte_training.rid = cte_99_9999_c.rid

ORDER BY cte_training.rid
```

I summarized the sql because it can wind up being a few thousand lines long. Note that in the table, the six digit codes (in the form of XX-XXXX) are actually data in the rows. It seems like maybe a pivot query (or 4) might make this more concise, but I have no idea if it would help or hurt performance.

Is there a better way to do this? Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Thanks to whoever retitled my question.  I was at a loss of how to describe this thing.

I've explored using the pivot approach and it runs orders of magnitude faster.  I wound up breaking it into 4 different queries, but that should be okay, I think.

I also found out from a previous developer that the list of codes is essentially static, so that helps a bit.

Here is what I'm working with now:

```
SELECT rid, 
[11-9111] AS [11-9111], [11-9121] AS [11-9121], [19-1042] AS [19-1042], [21-1010] AS [21-1010], [21-1011] AS [21-1011], [21-1090] AS [21-1090], [21-1091] AS [21-1091], [21-1094] AS [21-1094], [21-1798] AS [21-1798], [27-3091] AS [27-3091], [29-1031] AS [29-1031], [29-1050] AS [29-1050], [29-1125] AS [29-1125], [29-1126] AS [29-1126], [29-1127] AS [29-1127], [29-1128] AS [29-1128], [29-1140] AS [29-1140], [29-1190] AS [29-1190], [29-1199] AS [29-1199], [29-2011] AS [29-2011], [29-2012] AS [29-2012], [29-2021] AS [29-2021], [29-2030] AS [29-2030], [29-2031] AS [29-2031], [29-2032] AS [29-2032], [29-2034] AS [29-2034], [29-2035] AS [29-2035], [29-2040] AS [29-2040], [29-2041] AS [29-2041], [29-2042] AS [29-2042], [29-2050] AS [29-2050], [29-2051] AS [29-2051], [29-2052] AS [29-2052], [29-2053] AS [29-2053], [29-2054] AS [29-2054], [29-2055] AS [29-2055], [29-2060] AS [29-2060], [29-2061] AS [29-2061], [29-2070] AS [29-2070], [29-2071] AS [29-2071], [29-2090] AS [29-2090], [29-2099] AS [29-2099], [31-1010] AS [31-1010], [31-1011] AS [31-1011], [31-1012] AS [31-1012], [31-1014] AS [31-1014], [31-1015] AS [31-1015], [31-1016] AS [31-1016], [31-2010] AS [31-2010], [31-2011] AS [31-2011], [31-2012] AS [31-2012], [31-2020] AS [31-2020], [31-2021] AS [31-2021], [31-2022] AS [31-2022], [31-9010] AS [31-9010], [31-9090] AS [31-9090], [31-9091] AS [31-9091], [31-9092] AS [31-9092], [31-9093] AS [31-9093], [31-9094] AS [31-9094], [31-9095] AS [31-9095], [31-9097] AS [31-9097], [31-9099] AS [31-9099], [31-9999] AS [31-9999], [43-4171] AS [43-4171], [43-5031] AS [43-5031], [43-6013] AS [43-6013], [51-9081] AS [51-9081], [99-9999] AS [99-9999]
FROM

(SELECT rid, training_program_soc, 
    CASE WHEN LEN(LTRIM(vocational_degree_received)) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END  AS vocational_degree_received 
FROM _training) vdr

PIVOT
(
    SUM(vocational_degree_received)
    FOR
    training_program_soc IN
    ( 
[11-9111], [11-9121], [19-1042], [21-1010], [21-1011], [21-1090], [21-1091], [21-1094], [21-1798], [27-3091], [29-1031], [29-1050], [29-1125], [29-1126], [29-1127], [29-1128], [29-1140], [29-1190], [29-1199], [29-2011], [29-2012], [29-2021], [29-2030], [29-2031], [29-2032], [29-2034], [29-2035], [29-2040], [29-2041], [29-2042], [29-2050], [29-2051], [29-2052], [29-2053], [29-2054], [29-2055], [29-2060], [29-2061], [29-2070], [29-2071], [29-2090], [29-2099], [31-1010], [31-1011], [31-1012], [31-1014], [31-1015], [31-1016], [31-2010], [31-2011], [31-2012], [31-2020], [31-2021], [31-2022], [31-9010], [31-9090], [31-9091], [31-9092], [31-9093], [31-9094], [31-9095], [31-9097], [31-9099], [31-9999], [43-4171], [43-5031], [43-6013], [51-9081], [99-9999])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY rid
```

I'll probably retitle the columns to make them a little easier to identify.  I'll just do the different column tests in 3 more queries and maybe join them.

Comment: Get requirements start from scratch.

Comment: Post what your looking to achieve with it and maybe we can suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: Is `rid` either a unique or primary key on `_Training`?

Comment: It's weird how fast this question was closed for "Insufficient Information", since it is entirely likely that it can be answered based solely on the information already available.  This is why mods need to be both judicious and circumspect with this kind of voting.

Comment: Especially odd, since 90% of the SQL performance questions here initially do *NOT* have sufficient information, but they are normally given hours, even days to supply it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I actually was about to post an answer.

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah, me too.  Questions being closed by folks who are not sufficiently expert in the subject area is a pervasive problem here.  The moderators especially need to exercise more restraint, as to SQL Server experts, there is a likely answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

This one might prove an improvement:

```
WITH cte_training AS (
  SELECT
    rid,
    Training_program_SOC,
    Started     = CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_begin_date) = 1                                           THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    Completed   = CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_training_completed = 1       THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    Degree      = CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_degree_received is not NULL  THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    Certificate = CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND Vocational_license_received IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
  FROM _training
),
unpivoted AS (
  SELECT
    rid,
    Item = Training_program_SOC + ' ' + Item,
    Status
  FROM cte_training
  UNPIVOT (
    Status FOR Item IN (Started, Completed, Degree, Certificate)
  ) AS u
)

SELECT
  rid,

  [00-0000 Started], 
  [00-0000 Completed],
  [00-0000 Degree],
  [00-0000 Certificate],

  [11-9111 Started], 
  [11-9111 Completed],
  [11-9111 Degree],
  [11-9111 Certificate],

  ...

  [99-9999 Started], 
  [99-9999 Completed],
  [99-9999 Degree],
  [99-9999 Certificate]

FROM unpivoted
PIVOT (
  MAX(Status)
  FOR Item IN (
    [00-0000 Started], [00-0000 Completed], [00-0000 Degree], [00-0000 Certificate],
    [11-9111 Started], [11-9111 Completed], [11-9111 Degree], [11-9111 Certificate],
    ...
    [99-9999 Started], [99-9999 Completed], [99-9999 Degree], [99-9999 Certificate]
  )
) AS p
ORDER BY rid
;
```

Basically, the first CTE produces four status columns for every row based on same conditions as in your query.

The second CTE *unpivots* the statuses and merges the status names with `Training_program_SOC` values, to use them as column names at the final stage.

The main SELECT pivots the results of the second CTE using `Item` values as column names and `Status` as corresponding values. The two long column lists, one in the SELECT clause and the other in the PIVOT clause, are actually identical, so you only need to build the list once in your application before putting it into the dynamic query.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a  cross-tab query, something like this:

```
SELECT  rid,
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_begin_date) = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='00-0000') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [00-0000 Started],
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_training_completed = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='00-0000') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [00-0000 Completed],
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_degree_received IS NOT NULL AND Training_program_SOC='00-0000') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [00-0000 Degree],
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_license_received IS NOT NULL AND Training_program_SOC='00-0000') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [00-0000 Certificate],

    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_begin_date) = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='11-9111') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [11-9111 Started],
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_training_completed = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='11-9111') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [11-9111 Completed],
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_degree_received IS NOT NULL AND Training_program_SOC='11-9111') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [11-9111 Degree],
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_license_received IS NOT NULL AND Training_program_SOC='11-9111') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [11-9111 Certificate],
...
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_begin_date) = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='99-9999') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [99-9999 Started],
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_training_completed = 1 AND Training_program_SOC='99-9999') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [99-9999 Completed],
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_degree_received IS NOT NULL AND Training_program_SOC='99-9999') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [99-9999 Degree],
    ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISDATE(vocational_training_end_date) = 1 AND vocational_license_received IS NOT NULL AND Training_program_SOC='99-9999') THEN 'Yes' END)), 'No') [99-9999 Certificate],

FROM    _training
GROUP BY rid
ORDER BY rid
```

I'll let someone else post the `PIVOT` version of this...